# Как правильно складывать и сравнивать дату и время в php?

Tags: время, php, дата

```
$datenow = date("Y-m-d H:i");
if ($myrow['timeout'] < ($datenow + "0000-00-00 00:00")) {
    $onint = 1;
}else{
    $onint = 0;
}
```

но не совсем корректно работает (помогите разобраться - заранее спасибо!)

Comment: if ($datenow < $myrow['timeout'] + 1 минута) вот так надо сделать учитывая что время в формате yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s.. modyfy() - почему то выдает ошибку(

Comment: в переменную $myrow['timeout'] данные заносятся таким образом:

$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$resultonline = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET timeout='$date' WHERE id='$myrow2[id]'",$db);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если есть необходимость оперировать именно таким форматом даты — `Y-m-d H:i:s`, то желательно использовать класс [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php), а конкретнее — [DateTime::modify](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.modify.php). Пример:

```
$date = new DateTime('2013-06-16 23:53:16');
$date->modify('+1 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2013-06-17 23:53:16
```

Comment: А если минуту добавить надо то писать $date->modify('+1 minute');?

Comment: у меня не получается почему то $myrow['timeout']->modify('+1 day'); выдает ошибку((

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function modify() on a non-object in вот такую ошибку выдает при попытке(

Comment: все дело в том что почему то $myrow['timeout'] - оказался строкой! хотя в базе mysql он заносится в ячейку с параметром DATETIME

Comment: DATETIME в mysql — это совершенно не то же самое, что DateTime в PHP. Да, MySQL-ный тип DATETIME нужно рассматривать как строку.

    $myrow['timeout'] = new DateTime($myrow['timeout']);
    $myrow['timeout']->modify('+1 minute');

Answer (score 2):

Можно как вариант использовать время в цифровом варианте, который капает с 1970 года ( если не ошибаюсь). Чтобы узнать сколько уже секунд набежало можно воспользоваться функцией time(), для того, чтобы перевести, можно использовать функцию date().
Проверка делается очень просто:

```
if ($myrow['timeout'] < time()+15*60) { // При условии, что $myrow['timeout'] - тип поля int, а 15*60 - это 15 минут или сразу можно написать 900 секу

$onint = 1;

}else{

$onint = 0;}
```