# Прибавить 10 дней к дате

Tags: php

Допустим, есть такая дата: `24.12.2019`, мне необходимо прибавить к ней 10 дней, чтобы получилась следующая дата: `03.01.2020`. Как это реализовать на PHP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Как прибавить дни к числу? 28.11.2018 + 30 = 28.12.2018](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/899480/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%ba-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83-28-11-2018-30-28-12-2018)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/899480/256824 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/534272/256824 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/506340/256824 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229108/256824

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Прибавить 7 дней к текущей дате](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/534272/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-7-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo date('d.m.Y', strtotime('+10 day', strtotime('24.12.2019'))); // 03.01.2020
```

Answer (score 1):

Уж лучше по современному:

```
echo (new DateTime('24.12.2019'))->modify('+10 day')->format('d.m.Y');
```